# '--ssl=off' Error in Mysql 8.0.26 service startup

Tags: mysql, systemd, mysql8

I'm seeing an odd error in the `mysqld.service` status notes...

```
The syntax '--ssl=off' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use --tls-version=invalid instead.
```

The thing is I've disabled SSL using `skip_ssl` in the `/etc/my.cnf` and I don't see any vars relating to SSL defined in `/etc/my.cnf.d/*`.  I've also checked in `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/override.conf` and the only thing I've set is `LimitNOFILE`.

The `--ssl=off` setting is a command line start up variable, so where could this error be coming from?  Is there a new way to disable SSL other than `skip_ssl`?

I'm on Rockly Linux 8, and MySQL 8.0.26.

---

The pertaining documentation, including the deprecation note can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html

Answer (score 3):

I found in the docs finally that the `skip_ssl` is actually the same variable in `cnf` format that `--ssl` is in command line, so it was the error message ambiguity that led to my confusion.

The fix for this is to replace `skip_ssl` with `tls_version=''` as the former is now deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.26.

This has led to a number of new ssl related errors in the status so I'll post any notes I can after I solve them, hopefully this helps alleviate any confusion and saves you some time.

---

With regard to the new errors when using `tls_version=''`...

```
[Warning] ... [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
[Warning] ... [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: TLS version is invalid
[Warning] ... [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'
```

There is an [open bug report at oracle](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104587) outlining this behaviour, which I've added my voice to.

Comment: According to your original error message, your solution `--tls-version=''` should be replaced by `--tls-version=invalid`. Perhaps that will avoid running into another deprecated parameter message in the future.

Comment: @Ned64 thanks for the suggestion, but that's the command line option, the documentation indicates `tls_version=''` be used in the `my.cnf` format. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html

Comment: OK, thanks, I didn't know. Perhaps link the documentation in your Answer.

Comment: I doesn't matter if you're using underscores or dashes, and it also doesn't make a difference if the value is empty or "invalid". It always results in the server not starting with a log message of "Option --tls-version or --admin-tls-version is set to an invalid value", so I would stay with `skip-ssl` for the time being. I guess it's a bug or some MySQL developer is a real idiot. They also consider "default_authentication_plugin" deprecated, yet it's still the only way to set a default, if the first method in "authentication_policy" is "*" while deprecated things should in fact be dispensable.

Answer (score 1):

The function of the option `--tls-version=''` has now been fixed in MySQL 8.0.31:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html

> The alternative for the deprecated --ssl=off server option to disable
> the use of encrypted connections was not working as documented, or as
> presented in the deprecation warning. Setting the tls_version system
> variable to the empty value (tls_version='') now works correctly for
> this purpose. (Bug #106459, Bug #33858646)