# How can I disable SSL (TLS) in MySQL 8.0.36+?

Tags: mysql, mysql8

If I use `tls-version=''` in the config file, I'm getting the following warnings in the log:

```
[Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.
[Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: TLS version is invalid
```

If I use `ssl=off`, I get the following warning:

```
[Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--ssl=off' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use --tls-version='' instead.
```

As you see from this warning message, the server suggests me (`Please use --tls-version=''` ) to use the option that I initially described as one that gives a warning.

I also used the `skip_ssl` which is an alias for `ssl=off`, hence, it gives the same warning, that it is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

How can I properly disable SSL in MySQL version 8.0.36 or later so that I didn't have a warning in the config file on deprecated feature or failed to initialize or a version is invalid?

There was a similar report about the same problem in MySQL version 8.0.26 at ['--ssl=off' Error in Mysql 8.0.26 service startup](https://serverfault.com/questions/1090043/ssl-off-error-in-mysql-8-0-26-service-startup) but it was supposedly fixed in MySQL 8.0.31 according to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106459 -- however, this information is incorrect as I use MySQL 8.0.36 and the bug is still not fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I found this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/335957/how-do-i-disable-ssl-on-mysql-community-8-0-36-on-ubuntu-23-10

I do not know if this is related to your question, maybe it has the answer. The OP added:

I simply added "skip_ssl" in the [mysqld] section of my configuration file. I restarted the server (not sure if it was required). And, bingo! I was able to access my server using MySQL Workbench. I removed the line, to test the results. And, it apparently does not need to remain there.

Comment: I also tried skip_ssl because it is an alias for `ssl=off` and involves the same deprecated warning. I didn't mention that I was not able to access the MySQL workbench.